# C# - How can I specify in appsettings.json which interface implementation has to be used?

Tags: c#, interface, appsettings

I am working on a console application and I read configuration parameters from appsettings.json.
This is what appsettings.json looks like:

```
{
 "ConfigurationParameters": {
     "par1": "val1",
     "par2": "val2",
     "par3": [
       {
         "Id": 1,
         "value": val_1,
         "type": "type_1"
       },
       {
         "Id": 2,
         "value": val_2,
         "type": "type_2"
       }
     ]
 }
}
```

I read this file through

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); 
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            IConfiguration iConfiguration = hostContext.Configuration;
            Configuration Configuration = iConfiguration.GetSection("ConfigurationParameters").Get<Configuration>();

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        })
```

Configuration.cs:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public int par1 { get; set; }
    public int par2 { get; set; }
    public List<Type1OfPar3> par3{ get; set; }
}
```

TypeOfPar3.cs:

```
public class Type1OfPar3 : ITypeOfPar3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; } 
    public string type { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something;
    }
}
```

Everything works until this point.

Now I want to make List par3 more generic. In Configuration.cs, I would like to substitute `public List<Type1OfPar3> par3{ get; set; }` with `public List<ITypeOfPar3> par3{ get; set; }`.
In this way my list can contain all object whose class implements ITypeOfPar3.
I know that interface can not have direct implementation from appsettings.json, so my aim is to define, during initialization, the type of any par3 element, looking at variable “type” in appsettings.json.
Is that possible?

Otherwise how can I exploit interfaces and their implementations using appsettings.json?

The only workaround I found is to declare a generic class which implements the interface:

```
public class GenericTypeOfPar3 : ITypeOfPar3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; } 
    public string type { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething(){}
}
```

New Configuration.cs:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public int par1 { get; set; }
    public int par2 { get; set; }
    public List<GenericTypeOfPar3> par3{ get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a new List `public List<ITypeOfPar3> par3New{ get; set; }` (after the app settings reading) and run a function like that:

```
public void par3Setup()
{
    foreach (var par3Element in par3)
    {
        if (par3NewElement.type.Equals("Type1OfPar3"))
        {
            Type1OfPar3 par3El = new Type1OfPar3();
            par3New.Add(par3El );
        }
        else if (par3NewElement.type.Equals("Type2OfPar3"))
        {
            Type2OfPar3 par3El = new Type2OfPar3();
            par3New.Add(par3El );
        }
    }
}
```

Where Type2OfPar3 is another class implementing ITypeOfPar3.

Comment: Why do you want this? Configuration settings aren't meant to do anything, just represent values. They're extra-dumb DTOs, not entities.  They can easily be `record`s if the runtime allows it. The `why` matters - validation is a valid use case, but that *doesn't* require interfaces and inheritance. You can easily specify validation rules in another class. It will be a lot easier to test validation rules if they aren't hard-coded into the DTOs too

Comment: BTW interfaces can't be instantiated anywhere. You can't write `new IMyInterface(a,b)` no matter where `a` and `b` come from.